# On the invertibility of basis function matrix for interpolating functions

Tags: functions, inverse, interpolation, approximation-theory

Problem:
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies
$$
 f(y(x)) = g(x) \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^2
$$
where $y : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is a map that requires attention in this question.

Suppose $f$ is parameterizable in terms of coefficients $c_i, i=1,\dots,n$ with a set of basis functions $b_i$
$$
 f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i b_i(x) \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^2.
$$
Following the above definitions, we can say
$$
    g(x) = f(y(x)) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i b_i(y(x)) \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^2.
$$
Using the basis function representation for $g$ and considering $n$ distinct data points $(x_i, g(x_i))$, we form a linear system
$$
 \mathrm{g} = \mathrm{B_y c}
$$
where $\mathrm{g} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ stores data points $g(x_i)$, $\mathrm{B_y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a matrix stores the values of basis functions at $y(x_i)$, and $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ stores the coefficients.

I would like to find out the conditions on function $y$ that ensures the invertibility of matrix $ \mathrm{B_y}$.

My attempt:
Suppose $y$ is an identity map. Assuming $b$ is a set of monomial basis functions of degree at most $(n - 1)$, $B_y$ is known as a Vandermonde matrix. We know from the uniqueness theorem for interpolating polynomial that we obtain a nonsingular Vandermonde matrix if all data points $x_i$ are distinct.

This implies that, for a general function $y$, $B_y$ be invertible if $y$ has a unique map for each distinct point $x_i$. This means that $y$ should be an injective function to preserve the distinctness.

I am so far unable to comment on if the function needs to be a bijective, invertible, or even a differentiable function for $B_y$ be a nonsingular matrix.

Can you please comment on this problem?

Comment: this is going to depend partly on the "basis functions" $b_i$ and the sample points $x_i$. For example, it is possible that two of these basis functions will agree on a particular point $p$: $b_1(p) = b_2(p)$, even though they disagree elsewhere. If it so happens that $y(x_i) = p$, it may be that $B_y$ is not invertible no matter how nice $y$ is.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I agree with you. Basis function also plays a role here. I had mainly monomials and spline as a basis functions in my mind. I think if I assume $y$ is an injective function and data points $x_i$ are distinct, then basis functions will always be linearly independent. Hence $B_y$ is an invertible matrix.